# Textbook on the mathematics of RBC/DSGE models?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, dynamic-optimization, dsge, rbc

I'm reading David Romer's Macroeconomics. However, what I don't like is that he doesn't go at all into detail about the mathematical underpinnings of RBC/DSGE models. When it comes to the central mathematical parts of these models, such as how to derive and solve an expectational recurrence equation in a mathematically rigorous way, Romer instead treats it very hand-wavy and skips over steps.

Perhaps that is fine for some people, but I would like more mathematical rigour.

However, the problem is that every textbook I've found so far that is about mathematical economics only treats deterministic dynamic models.

**So my question is: Is there a good textbook that treats stochastic dynamic models in a mathematically rigorous way?** Note I am NOT talking about the econometric estimation of these models, but merely the purely theoretical treatment of dynamic stochastic models.

Answer (score 7):

The mathematical theory behind DSGE models can be found in any textbook on stochastic dynamic optimisation.

One common reference that economists use for this is [Stokey, Lucas and Prescott](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674750968). Of course, they focus exclusively on recursive methods, but (perhaps) the lion’s share of dynamic problems in economics are solved in this way.

There is also a treatment of dynamic optimisation (including non-recursive and/or continuous-time methods) in [Acemoglu](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8764.html).

Comment: I agree that Stokey, Lucas & Prescott has the most rigorous approach I've seen, to the point of being extremely dense. They even include a chapter on Measure Theory to justify swapping limits in and out of an integral.

Answer (score 1):

One I can introduce is " [**ABC of RBC**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674028147) "
It was so helpful to me.

Comment: Hi: Another one is "structural macro-econometrics" by dejong et al but I can't compare it to the other ones because I'm not famiiar with them. It seems pretty good on an absolute level but I haven't gone through all of it either.